# dnsmasq is not logging dns queries

Tags: networking, dns, 23.10, dnsmasq

Here's how I am debugging this issue from the command line:

```bash
$ dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries
```

Putting the `log-queries` option in the config file and running it as a daemon still showed nothing on the log file. I am expecting that when I do `dig example.com`, it should show up.

Here's the output from the command above:

```yaml
dnsmasq: started, version 2.89 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset nftset auth cryptohash DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
dnsmasq: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
dnsmasq: using nameserver 1.1.1.1#53
dnsmasq: using nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888#53
dnsmasq: using nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844#53
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 7 names
```

Ubuntu Version: 23.10
Kernel 6.5.0
dnsmasq version: 2.89

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If really using dnsmasq

Just do `dig @127.0.0.1 example.com` instead. For the whole system, skip to the **proper solution** below.

Your line `dnsmasq: using nameserver 8.8.8.8` shows that you edited `/etc/resolv.conf` away from systemd-resolved. Now the problem is not that dnsmasq isn't logging the queries. The problem is that the queries are not being sent to dnsmasq. Each application calls the `getaddrinfo` glibc function, and that looks at `/etc/resolv.conf`. In this case, `dig` is reading that file, and making the DNS requests to `8.8.8.8` directly, without asking `dnsmasq`.

systemd-resolved edits the `/etc/resolv.conf` file for a reason. It does that to point all DNS queries on the computer towards it using `127.0.0.53`. Doing that with `dnsmasq` just results in an infinite loop, because `dnsmasq` uses that file itself. `systemd-resolved` does not suffer from this problem because it uses `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. We can replicate that with the **proper solution**:

EDIT: Please see Pihhan's simpler answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1501802/1004020 . It does this except with less steps.

1. `sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv-for-dnsmasq.conf`
2. `echo 'nameserver 127.0.0.1' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf`
3. Start the server with `dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries -r /etc/resolv-for-dnsmasq.conf` instead
4. `dig example.com` and every other app should start benefiting from dnsmasq's caching

## If using systemd-resolved

Ubuntu 23.10 does not use `dnsmasq` by default. It uses `systemd-resolved`, so use the corresponding commands:

1. `sudo resolvectl log-level debug`
2. Do either your original `dig example.com` or use `resolvectl query --cache=0 example.com`
3. See the output at the top of `sudo journalctl -r -u systemd-resolved`
4. For privacy, turn debug back off with `sudo resolvectl log-level info`

Comment: I know it doesn't use it by default. I disabled `systemd-resolved` and then used dnsmasq. It can listen on port 53 but it doesn't log queries at all.

Comment: @SaadAhmed I found the real problem/solution and edited my answer

Comment: Default resolver has known and unfixed issues. Dnsmasq has some issues as well, but imo behaves better.

Answer (score 4):

Having extra resolv.conf is not necessary. Just prepend `nameserver 127.0.0.1` into */etc/resolv.conf* before other nameservers, which you have there now. Dnsmasq will detect its own address and skip itself. Advantage of such setup is it will also work when Dnsmasq is stopped or broken, just with some delay.

It will try first Dnsmasq, but if that returns failure or timeouts, will try following servers. Under normal circumstances only first server would be used.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't realize dnsmasq's failure to ignore 127.0.0.53 does not mean it did not support "dnsmasq: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface". Thank you for pointing this out.