# DNS Server issue on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dns

I have read tons of posts about DNS and fixing that but it was not solved.
I have a private virtual network and multiple VMs are connected to a router with internet. All of them have internet and successfully can ping with IP.
Some of the are working with the default network setting of Ubuntu.
Two of them have problem to ping with servername like `ping google.com`.
As I noticed there are many ways to solve it and the most successful one is to track with `resolvectl` and of there is not public DNS, add it. Here is the output of resolvectl when issue occurred (I did not change anything in the network or system that issue occurred):

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS
                    DNSSEC=no/unsupported
       DNS Servers: 192.168.10.3 192.168.10.4 192.168.10.2
```

So that I modified `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` by adding nameservers as follow:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:64:11:20
            mtu: 1450
            set-name: ens3
            nameservers:
              addresses: [4.2.2.4, 8.8.8.8]
```

After `netplan apply` that, the output of `resolvectl` adds this line:

```
       DNS Servers: 4.2.2.4 8.8.4.4 192.168.10.3 192.168.10.4 192.168.10.2
```

This modification does not help, so I tried with `resolvectl dns ens3 4.2.2.4 8.8.4.4` and the line `Current DNS Server: 4.2.2.4` was added. By this one of the VMs got ping with nameserver (which could be lost after reboot), and the other VM still fails to access.
Other solution that I applied and failed was editing the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file by adding `DNS=4.2.2.4`.
I really don't find any further solution that can help. Please keep in mind ping with ip works properly.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: You can enable debugging with the bottom half of my https://askubuntu.com/a/1501791/1004020 , then please [edit] your question with the relevant log output

Comment: here is the log of it, 
`> dig @127.0.0.1 google.com
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to #53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached`

Comment: "communications error to #53" means that the systemd-resolved service is not running. You should either enable and start it, or tell us which dns service you are using

Comment: But systemd is active, this is one of the systemd subservices
`sudo service systemd-sysctl status
● systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-02-08 21:06:37 UTC; 1h 1min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
             man:sysctl.d(5)
    Process: 458 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=>
   Main PID: 458 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 6ms`

Comment: `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: ● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; >
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-02-08 21:06:39 UTC; 1h 8min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-netwo>
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resol>
   Main PID: 645 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19139)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear that I was referring to the non-dnsmasq portion of that answer. I meant 1. `sudo resolvectl log-level debug` 2. `resolvectl query --cache=0 example.com` (NOT `dig`) 3. Look in `sudo journalctl -r -u systemd-resolved` for the interesting lines and/or [edit] your question with them